# How to place a symbol at certain address via the linker script?

Tags: c++, c, linker, embedded

It is about GNU Linker.

I have a (lets say) variable named `myVar`. Now I want my variable to be placed at certain address in the memory.

The compiler I use, has an `__attribute__ ((blablabla))` that does the trick. However I decide to use the linker script.

Since now I managed to place the variable at certain address from the linker script just like this:

```
myVar  = 0xDEAD;
```

And it actually works. The problem is that the linker is stupid and occasionally deploys other variables over the address of mine. And both in a way act like they are in a `union`.

I think that somehow I need to tell the linker that this address with this length is occupied and should not be touched.

Anyway I guess You get the idea. Any help?

Comment: Such paraibles are typically used for peripheral modules in OS or bare-metal embedded code. The correct place for them is in a header with macros. In a linker file, the address space they occupy is not available for regular variables. So, there is something wrong with you fundamental system design. See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by regular variables?

Comment: Variables managed by the compiler&linker, not your absolute addresses.

Answer (score 6):

I'd start to merge c source and linker.

Define a new section into linker script, like:

```
MEMORY
{
  ...
  my_data       (rwx) : ORIGIN = your_start_addr, LENGTH = section_length
}

SECTIONS
{
  /* ... */

  .myVarSection section_address :
  {
    KEEP(*(.mySection)) 
  } > my_data

  /* ... */
}
```

Then you can define your variable in source file like:

```
uint16_t __attribute__((section (".mySection"))) myVar = 0xDEAD;
```

Comment: Do you want to setup a seperate section for each absolute variable?

Comment: @Olaf It seems OP is trying to achieve such a "end-of-something"  threshold. Surely not a my solution for defining many variables at different absolute address.

Comment: That's why I asked for a MCVE. The question is not very clear. It has the haut-gout of an XY problem.

Comment: I think what @LPs suggested is near to what I have been searching for. The exception is that I don't want these `__attribute__` staff. I there approach to place them into `my_data` but from the linker script, not from the source file?
 
[link](https://github.com/RadoslavMarinov/stack-show/blob/2b48407df4965c2c54b2c8fadb43161ace2723f6/example.txt)

Comment: @Hairi Why do you want to do that using linker and not source files?

Comment: I personally think the ´__attribute__ ´ way of doing things is way cleaner (although compiler-specific) - As the programmer actually **sees** what's going on without referring to the linker script.

Comment: @Hairi: The standard way is to use neither, but simple macros. But you should use whatever your platform headers do. That makes your code consistent.